# Decoding Base64-encoded file in Rails takes too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-api

I get image files sent from an Android app to my Rails API.  I decode the images using this:

```
StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(image[1]))
```

The issue is that it takes too much time; on heroku it takes even longer.

Is there another way to do this that's faster and more efficient?

[image]

Comment: How long does it take? What size is the image? How long can it take?

Comment: 30s to 1 mint....1MB+

Comment: I quickly checked this on my machine and this is way faster (sub-second) for a 2.5MB file.

Are you sure the problem is with decoding? Perhaps it is with reading the file?

Comment: yes it takes time in conversion.........

Comment: let me attaach screen shot

Comment: @pascalbetz i attach screen shot...i take time in this

Comment: That Screenshot does not show much to me. Split the code in different lines and record the time it takes. I doubt that the decoding takes 30s.

Comment: @haseeb What are you using to time the Base64 decoding?  I ran a benchmark on a 2008-era Core2 Duo machine and a 1.7MB image took about 0.014 seconds to decode.  A 1988-era 80286 machine would be able to do this in less than 30 seconds, even including disk IO.  You must have something else going on in your code.  Please post the full code used to process this image, so that it can be evaluated properly to be able to answer your performance question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this for decode base64:

```
# this method for decode base64 code to file
  def parse_image_data(image[1])
    base64_file = image[1]
    ext, string = base64_file.split(',')

    ext = MIME::Types[base64_file].first.preferred_extension if ext.include?("base64")
    tempfile = Tempfile.new(["#{DateTime.now.to_i}", ".#{ext}"])
    tempfile.binmode
    tempfile.write Base64.decode64(string)
    tempfile.rewind
    tempfile
  end
```

Comment: This totally works for getting a base64 encoded image from a Vue frontend into ActiveStorage on a Rails backend. Thanks!